# SignalR Core exception handling and http error codes

Tags: c#, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

So i am trying out Signal R Core client in desktop application and have the following problem.
When trying to connect to a hub an HttpRequestException is thrown in case of error. The problem is that exception itself does not contain the Http Status code or any Http Headers returned from the Hub.
Is there any way this information could be obtained in case of failures ?
Thanks.